# ESP8266 not responding to AT commands from NUCLEO-L073RZ board?

Tags: stm32, esp8266, stm32cubeide, nucleo

I have interfaced esp8266 with NUCLEO-L073Rz board. I have used UART1(PA9, PA10) for esp communication and UART2 used for PC communication.

I also tapped the signal Tx from UART1 using CP2102 USB to ttl converter. So that I can see the AT commands send through UART1 Tx line. The following are the main codes.

```
  char *str2="UART2 start\r\n";
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *) str2, strlen(str2), 100);
  HAL_Delay(2000);

  str2="AT+CWJAP=\"mcserver\",\"m4mc1234\"\r\n";
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *) str2, strlen(str2), 100);
  HAL_Delay(9000);

  str2="AT+RST\r\n";
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *) str2, strlen(str2), 100);
```

But in the PC I have seen the following lines from UART1 Tx.

```
AT+CWJAP="mcserver","m4mc1234"
AT
```

The second command is not completely sending. So I have checked the Tx line of esp8266. Then I saw the following.

```
AT+CWJAP="mcserver","m4mc1234"
WIFI DISCONNECT
WIFI CONNECTED
WIFI GOT IP

OK
AT
```

The esp respond to first command without issues. But the second command is not completely received.

Then I verified the Tx line of UART1 by disconnecting the esp8266. Then I got the following.

```
AT+CWJAP="mcserver","m4mc1234"
AT+RST
```

So STM32 sends the data correctly and something is happening when I connect the esp8266.

Is there any things to do before sending AT command?

Edit:  I have got this code working by putting HAL_MAX_DELAY instead of 100. So what is that mean? Also it is not worked when increased delay to 100000.

After debugging, it is known that HAL_UART_Transmit gives HAL_ERROR. I understand it is due to the OVERRUN ERROR. So what is causing the overrun?

Comment: Maybe you have flow control enabled on one side but not the other?

Comment: flow control is not enabled.